# How to import a Svelte component into a JS file

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup

I'm working on a project using both of native JS and Svelte.
And I worked on a Svelte component and I want to know how can I import this later into my JS file.

```
*index.js*
// js code here 
alert('here is my sweet Svelte compoent');
-- the svelte component must be here ---
...
//

**MyComponent.svelte**

<script>
   ... the Svelte code ...
</script>
<style>
   ... the Svelte component's style ...
</style>
<div>
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do

```js
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent.svelte'
```

to create an instance of it you would then do

```js
new MyComponent({
  target: mountpoint // here the dom node where you want to mount it
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript ES6 the syntax to import svelte and anything else is below:

```
const svelte = require('svelte')
```

Comment: And don't forget to update the rollup.config.js file by simply adding

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget to update the *rollup.config.js* file by simply adding :

```
import svelte from "rollup-plugin-svelte";
```

and

```
svelte()
```

in the plugins' array
like this :

```
plugin : [
svelte()
```

]